# How to scroll from top after scrolling down like Facebook - Swift 4.2

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I want to implement scrolling functionality like Facebook app, where tap on Tab bar item if scrolling a page down and tap on same tab bar item it starts scrolling from top.

Here is my code -

```
override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {

        let indexOfTab = tabBar.items?.index(of: item)
        if indexOfTab == 0{
            let feed = HomeFeedViewController()
            feed.scrollToTop()
            print("pressed tabBar: \(String(describing: indexOfTab))")
        }else if indexOfTab == 1{
            print("pressed tabBar: \(String(describing: indexOfTab))")

        }else if indexOfTab == 2{
            print("pressed tabBar: \(String(describing: indexOfTab))")

        }else if indexOfTab == 3{
            let feed = QueueViewController()
            print("pressed tabBar: \(String(describing: indexOfTab))")

        }else if indexOfTab == 4{
            print("pressed tabBar: \(String(describing: indexOfTab))")

        }

    }


 func scrollToTop(){

        feedsTableView.setContentOffset(.zero, animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: try to give some codes where we can suggest

Answer (score 0):

Please try my code

```
var canScrollToTop:Bool = true
    func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) {

        // Allows scrolling to top on second tab bar click
        if (viewController.isKindOfClass(CustomNavigationBarClass) && tabBarController.selectedIndex == 0) {
            if (viewControllerRef!.canScrollToTop) {
                viewControllerRef!.scrollToTop()
            }
        }
    }


    // Scrolls to top
    func scrollToTop() {
        self.View.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: true)
    self.tblView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: true)
    self.collView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: true)
    }


    // Called when the view becomes available
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        canScrollToTop = true
    }

    // Called when the view becomes unavailable
    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        canScrollToTop = false
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Swift**

```
extension UIViewController {
    func scrollToTop() {
        func scrollToTop(view: UIView?) {
            guard let view = view else { return }

            switch view {
            case let scrollView as UIScrollView:
                if scrollView.scrollsToTop == true {
                    scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: -scrollView.contentInset.top), animated: true)
                    return
                }
            default:
                break
            }

            for subView in view.subviews {
                scrollToTop(view: subView)
            }
        }

        scrollToTop(view: self.view)
    }
}
```

**To use**

```
var previousController: UIViewController?

func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {

        //when user is in FeedViewController and scroll at last record and want to
        if previousController == viewController {
            if let navVC = viewController as? UINavigationController, let vc = navVC.viewControllers.first as? HomeViewController {

                if vc.isViewLoaded && (vc.view.window != nil) {
                    vc.scrollToTop()
                }
                print("same")
            }
        }
        else{
            print("No same")
        }

        previousController = viewController
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: I am making separate class for tabBarr controller and access in HomeFeedViewController. So where to write this code

Comment: implement this delegate method for separate class for tabBarr controller and check.

Comment: You need to tap twice, if tap again and it print "same" in log at that time it will go up. try to debug your case

Comment: My tableview not going to access, always getting nil values while tapping number of times

Comment: In my tableview has 7 custom cells, when I tap on first tab bar button then get crashed due to unexpectedly nil value for tablview.